# How to show nth div when click nth p tag using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a structure like this

```js
<div>
  <p></p> 1
  <p></p> 2
  <p></p> 3
  <p></p> 4
  <p></p> 5
   .   .  
   .   .  
   .   .  
</div>

<div></div> 1
<div></div> 2
<div></div> 3
<div></div> 4
<div></div> 5
 ..    ..   
 ..    ..   
 ..    ..
```

There are exactly equal number of p tags and div tags( don't consider the div containing the p itself)

Initially all the `<div></div>` are hidden (Except the div containing `<p></p>` tags)

Question:
1) I want that when the nth p tag is clicked I want to show nth div.

Comment: You want  based on the selected `<p>` tags to open up the `<div>` that it's referencing from? Example `<p></p>1` to open `<div></div>1`

Answer (score 1):

You can consider the text inside the element. You can match the *index* of clicked *p* element based on which you can show the specific *div* element:

```js
$('p').click(function(){
  var index = $(this).index();
  $('div').not('.pContainer').eq(index).show();
})
```

```css
div{display: none;}
.pContainer{display: block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pContainer">
  <p>1</p> 
  <p>2</p> 
  <p>3</p> 
  <p>4</p> 
  <p>5</p> 
</div>
*********
<div>1</div> 
<div>2</div> 
<div>3</div> 
<div>4</div> 
<div>5</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for reply but, I want to put something else in lower div.

Comment: @TusharJajodia, what you want to put inside the matching div?

Comment: Messages from Database

Comment: Actually the thing is The initial <p> tags will contain the name of the person and the corresponding <div> tags below will contain all the conversation. So when user will click the <p> tag i want to show them the full message. Hope making little sense

Comment: @TusharJajodia, this is completely different issue regarding collecting the information from Database. I will suggest you to post different question for that......

Answer (score 0):

try this and let me know if it worked

```js
function paraClick(index) {
  $('.p_click').css('display','none')
  $('.p_click').eq(index).css('display','block')
}
```

```css
.p_click{display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p onclick="paraClick(0)">P 1</p> 
  <p onclick="paraClick(1)">P 2</p> 
  <p onclick="paraClick(2)">P 3</p> 
  <p onclick="paraClick(3)">P 4</p> 
  <p onclick="paraClick(4)">P 5</p>
</div>

<div class="p_click">D 1</div> 
<div class="p_click">D 2</div> 
<div class="p_click">D 3</div> 
<div class="p_click">D 4</div> 
<div class="p_click">D 5</div>
```

Comment: Isn't there any way i can know how many prev sibling are there of the particular item that i have clicked.